# I want to open my app from sms

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating an app that will send the data thru the sms . now i want that when user tap that sms then my app will open with that data sended in the link in sms.

Comment: Users don't "click" on iOS.  They tap, touch, swipe, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [a custom URL scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50).

Comment: So if i send that URL in sms to another iPhone and in that iPhone (if my app installed) my app will open using this link?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using URL scheme. For reference you can see this [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50). And for implementation checkout this [mobile.tutsplus tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/). And [this link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) is also good to learn URL scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Allow your application to respond to some url (eg: myapp://launch ) and include the url in the SMS, when the user launches that URL your application will launch.

Take a look at this [launching-application-via-url-scheme](http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/iphone-development/launching-application-via-url-scheme/)

Enjoy Programming!!